# It's possible to construct a disjoint sequence of open balls with center elements of a sequence in a metric space

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ a complete metric space, if $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is  a non constant sequence such that $x_n \to x$. I try to construct a sequence of disjoint open balls with center in $x_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I have this idea, like $x_n \to x$, we know that $(d(x_n,x))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is decreasing and $d(x_n,x) \to 0$, using this, I pose the sequence of open balls $(B(x_n,r_n))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ where $r_n=\dfrac{1}{2}\min\{d(x_n,x_{n-1}),d(x_n,x_{n+1})\}$. With this, I proved that $B(x_n,r_n)\cap B(x_{n+1},r_{n+1})=\emptyset$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, but I can't prove that $B(x_n,r_n)\cap B(x_m,r_m)$ for all $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $m \not = n$. Is this true?, Can you help me with any ideas?

Comment: This is not possible if $x_n$ is a constant sequence. You'll need more restriction, perhaps $x_n \neq x$ $\forall n$?

Comment: @ClementYung Sure, the sequence is not constant. I skipped this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As highlighted in my comment, this is not possible if $x_n = x$ for some $n \in \Bbb{N}$, so we shall assume that's not the case.

Your example fails for $X = \Bbb{R}$, with $x_0 = x_2 = 4$, $x_1 = \frac{1}{2}$, and $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ for $n \geq 3$. Then $x_n \to 0$, but $B(x_1,r_1)$ contains all of $x_n$ for $n \geq 3$.

The construction is actually simple (if you do not require explicit formulae for each $r_n$). For each $k \in \Bbb{N}$, since $\lim_{k \to \infty} x_k \not\to x_n$, $x_n \in \{x_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is isolated so there exists $r_n > 0$ such that $x_k \notin B(x_n,r_n)$ for all $k \neq n$. Choose such an $r_n$ for each $n$, and you have a sequence of disjoint open balls with each centering around $x_n$.

Comment: That it's true, thank you very mouch.